# Rmarkdown separate printing elements with space

Tags: r, printing, r-markdown, alignment, cat

I am looking for printing in R markdown with the following layout on a single line:

Date: 25-04-2022                  Number: numerotrade               Time: 13:24:59

That is, I would like to have the first element on the extreme left of the page, the second one in the middle and the third one on the right. Or in other words, to add space between the vectors. How can I do that? currently the output that I have is all consecutive:

Date: 25-04-2022 Number: numerotrade Time: 13:24:59

Here is my code:

````
``` {r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat(c("Trade Date:",format(Sys.Date(), format="%d-%m-%Y")),c("Trade Number:",numerotrade),c("Execution time:",strftime(input$time)))```
````

Numero trade and input$time come from my code, you can replace with anything you want if you need to execute.

Thank you

Comment: @user2554330 my question is totally different from the the issue you have associated. I want to increase the space between elements INSIDE a R Chunk and INSIDE a Cat function, would you be able to help?

In other words, I want to increase the horizontal space...

Comment: Looks like the same issue to me.  You want to insert `\hfill` in the LaTeX output.  If you're after HTML output, see the linked post.

Comment: I am sorry, @user2554330. It might be because of my limited knowledge but I do not understand how `\hfill` could work into `cat()`

Comment: Just include `"\\hfill"` in the `cat()` call between the components that you want to separate.  You need to double the backslash because R treats it as an escape.

Comment: Thank you, truly appreciate! Indeed, my issue was that I wasn't understanding it was treating it as escape